# do_shortcode for twitter doesn't work well

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I have problem in show tweet in single.php template.

So I use this way to echo the tweet like this :-

```
$check_embeds=$GLOBALS['wp_embed']->run_shortcode( '[tweet 567061791826382849]' );
echo $check_embeds;
```

But not work, But  i read `https://en.support.wordpress.com/twitter/twitter-embeds/` and put the shortcode like above code but not work.

When i copy this `[tweet 567061791826382849]` to wp-admin in editor and show post, I can show tweet

Any Solution

Comment: Are you talking about wordpress.com or .org?

Comment: i have website by using wordpress cms

Comment: When you add full twitter embed URL in editor like `https://twitter.com/nacin/status/319508408669708289` WP automatically embeds and displays the tweet. I doubt there is shortcode like `[tweet]` in default.

Comment: i see my problem in single.php not in editor, i need to add this tweet in code php not in editor :-)

Comment: How about this. `echo apply_filters( 'the_content', 'https://twitter.com/nacin/status/319508408669708289' );`

Comment: i try this `<?php the_content(); echo apply_filters( 'the_content', 'https://twitter.com/nacin/status/319508408669708289' ) ?>` and show me `https://twitter.com/nacin/status/319508408669708289`

Answer (score 0):

You are linking to a support page for wordpress**.com**. While the basic Core WordPress is the same, that is a hosting service and it runs some code that is not part of Core. What you see there may not work on a self-hosted WordPress install. [What should work](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds), however, is this:

```
do_shortcode('[embed]https://twitter.com/nacin/status/319508408669708289[/embed]');
```